# jQuery alert not alerting

Tags: jquery, alert

Below is some script I'm using for a form. Everything works great except for the very last alert. It's pointing to input #address_province. If a customer's address is one of those in the list (shown for testing purposes are values WA, AL, GA) I'd like an alert, otherwise they can proceed. Currently nothing happens no matter what I put in the state field...I can proceed regardless. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

```
<script>
// Hides shipping info fieldset if ship to billing is checked
$(function () {
    $("#ship_to_billing").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) $("#shipping_info").hide();
        else $("#shipping_info").show();
    });
});

// Validates address fields are filled out unless ship to billing is checked...   
function validateShipping() {
    if (!$("#ship_to_billing").is(":checked")) {
        var inputs = $("#shipping_info input");
        var ready = true;
        inputs.each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                ready = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (!ready) {
            alert("Please tell us where to send this. Either choose ship to Billing Address or fill out both the Recipient Name as well as Shipping Address fields. Thanks!");
            return false;
        }
    }
        // Makes sure age verification is checked 
        if (!$('#age_verification').is(':checked')) {
            alert("Please verify you are 21 years of age or older.");
            return false;       
        }   
    }
       // Confirms province is allowed for wine shipping 
        if (!$('#address_province').val() == "WA") {
            alert("Shipping gifts containing alcohol to this state is prohibited by law. Please choose another item.");
             return false;       
        }
 return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have a `return false` . Please revisit the flow

Comment: `!$('#address_province').val() == "WA"` should probably be `$('#address_province').val() != "WA"`

Comment: Your `}` before the `if (!$('#address_province').val() == "WA") {` closes your `function validateShipping() {`. So, typo ;o)

Comment: what's the exclamation point for in this line? `alert("Shipping gifts containing alcohol to (!$('#address_province').val) is prohibited by law. Please choose another item.");`

Comment: seems to be some seriously messed up `}`'s. once that's fixed, it'l be up to the conditionals which look correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo. (extra })

Comment: Thank you jbabey, jsmorph, Joe T and Kevin B for your comments. Much appreciated. karthikr: you seem to be the only one that noticed I messed up the return false, thank you for catching that. What can I say..I'm new. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct condition there would have to be:

```
if ($('#address_province').val() != "WA") {
```

**EDIT**

Also the primary issue as pointed out by @jsmorph in the comments is that the:

> Your `}` before the `if (!$('#address_province').val() == "WA") {` closes your function `validateShipping() {`.

Comment: `Currently nothing happens no matter what I put in the state field...`  While you pointed out a logical flaw, it doesn't address the OP's concern.

Comment: @SableFoste `!$('#address_province').val()` will always return a boolean value, which compared with "WA" (which is the value used there) will always evaluate to `false`. No matter if the value is empty or not, the resulting condition `true == "WA"` or `"false == "WA"` will always be `false`. So while I pointed out a logical flaw, it was one that stops code execution from ever reaching the `alert()`. This might as well be the issue here.

Comment: Okay, fair enough... I agree.  I tried to remove the down vote, but it is locked in by SO unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @SableFoste Edited the answer to include the main issue as pointed out in the comments. I don't mind the downvote myself, but the answer is valid and it might mislead future viewers into thinking it's wrong from the start.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Sorry if it seemed obvious, I'm new to this. Bogdan, I appreciate very much your response & am attempting to implement it. However, it appears someone edited my post deleting some values. Currently my post only shows "WA", but there were a few others. With just one value this works beautifully (thanks again!) but if I try to put several of them, it returns false for anything I type in the field. What I have now is: 
if ($('#address_province').val() != "AK", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "WA") {         Clearly I am doing something yet again incorrectly..any idea what it is?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Had to make an array. So, have         var statesAllowed = ["AK", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "WA"];                  if ($('#address_province').val() != statesAllowed) {                 Thanks again, got it all squared away! Appreciate your help!